# i have propblem for getting apk from my app in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, apk

first of all i go in to my android folder in the main folder of my project
and do the below command

```
sudo  ./gradlew clean


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See 
https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
12 actionable tasks: 12 executed
```

and after that i do things below but i cant get my apk

```
sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease

> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/@react-native- 
community/async- 
storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java 
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-fs:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/react-native- 
fs/android/src/main/java/com/rnfs/RNFSManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/react-native-gesture- 



handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: resolve_projpath: path `/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test`: open: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test: Operation not permitted. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere


events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: resolve_projpath: path `/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test`: open: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test: Operation not permitted
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:95:23)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at BunserBuf.process (/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/bser/index.js:292:10)
    at /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/bser/index.js:247:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on WatchmanWatcher instance at:
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/lib/WatchmanWatcher.js:130:10)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at BunserBuf.<anonymous> (/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:107:12)
    at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test/node_modules/bser/index.js:249:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  watchmanResponse: {
    error: 'resolve_projpath: path `/Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test`: open: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test: Operation not permitted',
    version: '4.9.0'
  }
}

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 9s
109 actionable tasks: 109 executed
```

i dont know what should i do for this problem .
when i run this task my code configure 100%
and executing go till 73%
and the errors just happen.
i think by myself the error source is from the warning from the something imported to project and my laptop os is OSX

Answer (score 0):

Error stack is little confusing and not pointing to the real cause of issue, there could be multiple reasons. But you can try following:

- Check your metro builder is running while generating build. If not, you can do it from your root dir as "react-native start".
- If metro builder is running, make sure no other Node process is running on the same port.
- I would suggest you to rename your parent dir "react project" to something without space like "react_project". I'm making guess from statement `Error: resolve_projpath: path [...]` Also it is recommended to have directory structure names without spaces, which may lead to unsuccessful command operations.
- From statement `error: 'resolve_projpath: path` /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test`: open: /Users/erfanesfahanian/Desktop/react project/Test: Operation not permitted',` I think you should check/change the permission of directory in which you are handling your project. To verify, open your **android** directory with **Android Studio** (Admin Access) and build your project from there, if it compiles successfully, then it must be permission issue.